# How can I make a list plot from three arrays, plotting values of the 2nd and 3rd arrays against the 1st?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Very new to Mathematica, so pardon my ignorance.

I am trying to plot `x` vs `y1` and `x` vs `y2` on the same `ListPlot`.

Here is what the data look like:

`x = {1,2,3,4}`

`y1 = {3,4,5,6]`

`y2` results from FindIteration and gives me a result like this:

`y2 = {{5},{6},{8},{9}}`

How can I convert `y2` such so it has the same shape as `x` and `y1`?

My iteration code is

```
Do[y2new = 
  ynew /. FindInstance[
    function1[x[[i]], ynew] == function2[x[[i]], ynew], ynew, Reals];
 y2[[i]] = ynew, {i, Length[x]}]
```

Is there a way to change the assignment of `y2` values so the resulting array `y2` has the same shape as `x` and `y1`?

Comment: You could write `y2[[{i}]] = ynew`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
y1 = {3, 4, 5, 6};
y2 = {{5}, {6}, {8}, {9}};
```

To correct `y2` when has been already generated, you just need to apply [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) to `y2` and then plot the transpose of `x` and the flattened `y2`.

```
ListPlot[
  {Transpose[{x, y1}], Transpose[{x, Flatten[y2]}]}, 
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"y1", "y2"}]]
```

[image: plot]

Now let's look into generating the flat form of `y2` directly. You did provide definitions for the two functions for which you are giving `FindInstance`, so I will use these two

```
f1[x_, y_] := Sin[x + 2 π y]
f2[x_, y_] := Cos[x + 2 π y]
```

I will use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) in its operator form, `/@`, to generate the list `y2`. Doing so will make the code much simpler than your Do-loop.

```
N[FindInstance[f1[#, y] == f2[#, y] && 0 <= y <= 1, y]][[1, 1, 2]] & /@
```

x

> `{0.465845, 0.30669, 0.147535, 0.98838}`

Note tha t I use the part specification `[[1, 1, 2]]` to extract the numerical values for the list of instance found by `FindInstance`. Were I to use the usual extraction method

```
y /. N[FindInstance[f1[#, y] == f2[#, y] && 0 <= y <= 1, y]] & /@ x
```

I would get

> `{{0.465845}, {0.30669}, {0.147535}, {0.98838}}`

a list of the same shape as the one that you generate.

Comment: The Flatten command did the trick for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4}
y1 = {3, 4, 5, 6}
y2 = {{5}, {6}, {8}, {9}}
data = MapThread[{{#1, #2}, {#1, #3}} &, {x, y1, Catenate@y2}]
ListPlot[Transpose@data]
```